# EditText setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER); don't work

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, numeric

I am try using create one editText that only receive numeric (only appears numeric keyboard). On nexus 7 that don't happen :X

this is my code:

```
    EditText edit = new EditText(context);
    edit.setText(value);
    edit.setTextSize(16);
    edit.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
    edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
            | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
    edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            elem.setValue(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
        }
    });
```

Can you help me?

EDIT:

i am add this EditText to a LinearLayout like this:

```
    myLinearLayout.addView(edit);
```

Comment: May be your EditText is being re-drawn, try setting INPUT_TYPE through the xml. Not sure if this is will sort out things, but worth giving a try. And more over, this will show Numeric Keys and hide Alpha-keys, but Symbol-Keys will still be inflated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this it will help you

change, instead of this line

```
edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

change like below

```
edit.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER |InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use  [TextView.setRawInputType()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setRawInputType%28int%29), the java equivalent of android:inputType

Answer (score 1):

That's not what numeric does.  Numeric is a hint to the keyboard that it should show a numberpad.  It does not force the keyboard to do that, and it does not prevent other keys (like +, -, #, *, etc) from being shown or entered.  If you want to prevent certain characters from being entered, you have to do that app side.  If you want to do that, you need to set an InputFilter on the edit field.

Here's some code for that:

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() { 
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, 
Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) { 
                for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 
                        if (!Character.isDigit(source.charAt(i))) { 
                                return ""; 
                        } 
                } 
                return null; 
        } 
}; 
edit.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

Comment: Thx.. i gonna use that ;) i only want numeric numbers :)